# ios 6 - an app which allows user to create mapannotations while on the street returns multiple annotations with same coordinates

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Im building an app that lets a user build his own map annotations while he walks around the neighbourhood. Im testing this right now.

Everything works smoothly Im seeing that when Im out on the street and I create mapannotations they show up on the device maps instantly. The problem is that sometimes I see that after creating multiple ones they all show up as a single pin. ie they have the same latitude and longitude but they have different title and subtitles. This means the program is actually creating separate objects but assigning them the same coordinates.

I checked to make sure that the program isn't rewriting an old object when a new one is created.

Seems that either the CLlOcation manager is providing the same coordinates. Im not sure how to proceed with this.

Could the CLLocation Manager be giving wrong coordinates?

Thanks

This is the code that I implemented in my cllocationmanager instance

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)_manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {
   NSLog(@"%s %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
   self.userLocation = newLocation;
   NSLog(@"USer location latitude = %.4f", self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude );
   NSLog(@"USer location longitude = %.4f", self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
   if (self.userLocation)
   {
        [_locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];
    }

   }
```

---

EDIT

I guess just to be specific, what Im trying to understand is how do I get updated readings of the user location within my app, that is the same values as the blue dot that constantly animates the users' location such that it moves whenever the user moves. I cannot seem to get that reading from the CLLocation manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will often get one old reading when you turn on Location Manager. You should check the timestamp and horizontalAccuracy of the reading before deciding to use it.

Comment: Thanks. However, It would be great to know how to get a refreshed reading from the CLLOcation manager and avoid getting the same reading